# Counting null values to store in an array : javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures, counter

Alright... I've been stuck on this for a while

I'm trying to grab the count of the each leader's(leaderDisplay) dateExit value that equals === ""  and store it into an array

The output im trying to get is something like ['Albert Owens','Tina Snow','Rick Sanchez']  [2,1,2]

This is where I've gotten so far and I'm pretty sure i'm over thinking it...

```
const data = [
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

const allExit = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.fieldData.dateExit;
});

const dateExits = allExit.filter(onlyUnique);

const allSupervisors = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.fieldData.leaderDisplay;
});
const supervisors = allSupervisors.filter(onlyUnique);

let array = [];
let countArr = [];
let textColors = [];

supervisors.forEach(function (f, i) {
  let count = 0;
  if (f != "") {
    let stat = f;

    if (stat == "") {
      countArr.push(count);
    }
    let obj = {
      name: stat,
    };
    let keysArr = [];
    let statArr = [];
    supervisors.forEach(function (e, i) {
 
      let sup = e;
      let list = data
        .filter(function (e) {
          return (
            e.fieldData.leaderDisplay === sup &&
            e.fieldData.dateExit === ""
          );
        })
        .map(function (e) {
          return e.fieldData.ID;
        });

      statArr.push(list.length);
      keysArr.push(list);
    });
  
    if (Array.isArray(statArr) && statArr.length > 0) {
      obj.data = statArr;
      obj.keys = keysArr;
    }

    obj.keys;
    array.push(obj);

    return array;
  }

  return array;
});

const categories = supervisors;

const series = array;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count the number of empty `dateExits` for each `leaderDisplay` into an object. If you want to then produce two arrays (of names, and values), just use `Object.keys` and `Object.values`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "", dateHire: "06/14/2004", leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const { leaderDisplay, dateExit } = obj.fieldData;
  acc[leaderDisplay] = (acc[leaderDisplay] || 0) + (dateExit === "")
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)

const names = Object.keys(result)
const values = Object.values(result)
console.log(names)
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of use case is one where [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) comes in very handy.  It iterates over all elements in an Array and modifies the accumulator accordingly.  Since each elemement in your data only contains `fieldData`, deconstruction (`{ fieldData:elem }`) has been used in the parameters to pull `fieldData` out of each element as `elem` before processing.

```js
data = [
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Tina Snow",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Albert Owens",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "07/14/2006",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
  {
    fieldData: {
      dateExit: "",
      dateHire: "06/14/2004",
      leaderDisplay: "Rick Sanchez",
    },
  },
]

let accumulator = {}

results = data.reduce( ( accum, { fieldData:elem } ) => {
  accum[elem.leaderDisplay] = (accum[elem.leaderDisplay] || 0) + ((elem.dateExit === "") ?  1 : 0);
  return accum
}, accumulator);

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Right?  Reduce takes some getting used to, but is powerful